# jQuery ready function outside of page

Tags: jquery, document-ready

We have a website that uses javascript, prototype for client scripting, We are starting to use jQuery now and convert from prototype. I understand little of jQuery but I have enough knowledge to get around.

I ran into a problem, is it possible to do like a global load of  `$(document).ready(function(){});` because we have a lot of js files and I want to be able do use `jquery('#button').click()` and things like that.

Only examples I have seen is on the page itself not a js file. Please post a short example code if possible thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use it in a JS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(document).ready()` from an included js file, just make sure you use put the `<script>` include after the jquery include so the `$` function is available.

Edit:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

// file.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do whatever you want when the document finishes loading...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the `$(document).ready(function()` in an external javascript file. I usually do it for code that needs to run in the master page.

Also the shorthand for it is `$(function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `$(document).ready(function() {});` in an external javascript file.  Just place it in such a way that jQuery is loaded before your other external file.  Also if you are still using Prototype on the page make sure to use [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) as required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i figured out what the problem was. Forgetting # in id selector.